# Using font-lock regexp groups

Tags: font-lock

```
(defun pretty-add-keywords (mode keywords)
      (font-lock-add-keywords
       mode (mapcar (lambda (kw) `(,(car kw)
                                   (0 (prog1 nil
                                        (compose-region (match-beginning 0)
                                                        (match-end 0)
                                                        ,(cdr kw))))))
                    keywords)))
```

This function currently lets me match a regexp and replace it with a single char. I've been trying to modify it so that instead of just replacing it with a fixed char it replaces it with a group from the regex.

Would anybody be able to help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Could you post an example of the end result, and also how you all the function today.

Comment: [Here](http://imgur.com/gUE4Krf) is what it looks like before I call the function. [This](http://imgur.com/jnmBxj9) is what it looks like after.

Comment: Ok, so far so good. Could you give an example of what want to accomplish, which doesn't work today?

Comment: Basically instead of just replacing a static char I wanted to be able to extract a group. So for example if I had `array[x]` I would want to be able to replace (visually) that with just `x`. I know font lock uses regexps internally but I haven't found a way to access the groups.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will hide the "array[" and "]" parts using the `invisible` text property. It is a different approach compared to using `compose-region`, as suggested in the question.

```
(defun my-hide-array ()
  (make-variable-buffer-local 'font-lock-extra-managed-props)
  (add-to-list 'font-lock-extra-managed-props 'invisible)
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil
                          '(("\\(\\_<array\\_>\\[\\)[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\(\\]\\)"
                             (1 '(face nil invisible t))
                             (2 '(face nil invisible t))))))
```

You can add this function to a suitable major mode hook.

Using `compose-region` would probably not be a good idea -- the replacement text would probably not be editable, so you would have to disable the font-lock rule from time to time to edit your source code.

Note that the function matched only simple cases, where the array is indexed by a simple variable or constant. If you would like to handle the case with complex expression (maybe even nested occurrences of `array`), you would need to replace the regexp with an elisp function to do the match (using tools like `forward-sexp`). It can either apply the `invisible` text property itself or set up a "fake" match data structure and continue using the font-lock rule as is.

Comment: What does the `\\_<` and the `\\_>` part do? `\<` allegedly denotes the beginning of a word, but what is `\\_<`? And what is the underscore after `9` for?

Comment: It denotes the beginning of a symbol. For example, take the symbol `this_is_a_symbol`. The regexp `\\<this\\>` will match it, whereas `\\_<this\\_>` won't.

Comment: @lotolmencre see `C-h i g (elisp)Regexp Backslash`